# 'Dream' of Lord Shiva

Tags: shiva, gods, dream

What does it mean to see Lord Shiva in a dream? What Hindu scriptures tell about this?

Comment: It's an excellent dream to see Lord in dreams...

Comment: You had such dream because your subconscious & unconscious mind have impressions of Lord Shiva. You might be his devotee in past lives.

Comment: I have generalized your question to make it on topic here, which is equivalent to your question. Still, if you are unsatisfied or want to make additional changes you can edit or revert it back. But ensure, it turns out to be on topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good sign or a guidance to be followed which you decipher by yourself what it could be. More likely it seems a guidance. Lord Shiva says thus in 11th chapter of Shiv Rahasya

> 129. My Signs are of two kinds, those that endure and those that pass away. The enduring ones are the Sky, the Earth, the Sun, the Moon, the Stars, the Mountains and the Sea. The passing ones are of three kinds. Things that come to pass in daily life, visions and dreams. **Some are a guidance to be followed, some are a good tiding and some are an ill omen or a warning.** A human form of handsome features, **a Radiant One (a God)**, a holy man, a King or Queen; the Sun's or one's own clear reflection in water, a bright cloud, a rainbow or a sky-blue light; riding upon a horse, white bull or elephant; women, children and wild beasts being kind towards each other and to oneself; dwelling in a sheltered place or a well-kept house; eating pure food, wearing pure apparel in the day and resting in a pure bed at night; flying into the bright Sky, **being in beautiful surroundings, being in the company of good friends or Gods**; lying down with the head towards the South; casting a clear, unbroken and unshaken shadow; a growing plant; a running stream or lotus pond; a pleasant scent. **These are auspicious Signs (Sulakshana)** to be sought whilst waking, dreaming or seeing a vision. For they all are boding well.

Answer (score 7):

**States of Consciousness and [Dreams](http://www.veda.harekrsna.cz/encyclopedia/dreams.htm)**

Modern materialistic science is not sure about the origin and nature of most psychic phenomena including dreams. This information can be found in Vedic scriptures.

Srimad Bhagavatam 6.16.53-54, 7.7.25 or 7.15.61 describes three material states of consciousness:

1. jagrata, awakened state
2. svapna, dreaming state
3. susupti, deep sleep

> Dreams are created by the Supersoul to award the living entity with
>   the results of insignificant karma. (Vs 3.2.1) SB 6.16.55
>
> The Supersoul causes objects of desire to appear in dreams as they do
>   in other situations (e.g. the waking state). (Vs 3.2.2) SB 11.13.32
>
> Dreams are features of the Supreme Lord's maya. (Vs 3.2.3) SB 11.13.33
>
> Some dreams are omens; sastra and experts so declare. (Vs 3.2.4) SB
>   10.42.26-27

As [stated](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/22/40) in SB 11.22.40

> janma tv ātmatayā puṁsaḥ  sarva-bhāvena bhūri-da viṣaya-svīkṛtiṁ
>   prāhur  yathā svapna-manorathaḥ
>
> O most charitable Uddhava, what is called birth is simply a person’s
>   total identification with a new body. One accepts the new body just as
>   one completely accepts the experience of a dream or a fantasy as
>   reality.

Our religious scriptures contain profuse description of the dreams and their effects. In Sundar kand of Ramayana, an ogress Trijata relates her dream to her companion that in the dream, she had seen Ravan with tonsured head and going to the south riding an ass and that there was great stampede in Lanka. It is well known that within a month, her dream came true as Hanumana caused devastation by setting Lanka on fire that resulted in a great stampede [there](http://mantrashlokas-madhuri.blogspot.ca/2011/08/do-dreams-affect-human-life-by.html).

> TRIJATA NAAM RAKSHASI EKA, RAAM CHARAN RATI NIPUN BIBEKA ||SABANHU
>   BOLI SUNAESI SAPANA, SEETAHI SEI KAREHU HIT APANA || SAPANEN BANAR
>   LANKA JAARI, JAATU DHAAN SAINA SAB MAARI || KHAR AARURH NAGAN
>   DASASEESA, MUNDIT SIR KHANDIT BHUJ BEESA|| EHI BIDHI SO DACHCHHIN DISI
>   JAI, LANKA MANAHU VIBHISHAN PAI || NAGAR PHIRI RAGHUBIR DOHAI, TAB
>   PRABHU SEETA BOLI PATHAI ||

This [Swapeneshwari](https://www.gurushakti.org.in/165/sadhna/shakti/mantra-for-lucid-dreaming) Mantra is practiced for lucid dreaming at night. The mantra also helps you to know the answers of many questions of your life.

> **Sanskrit Mantra :** ॐ क्रीं क्रीं क्रीं ह्रीं ह्रीं स्वप्नेश्वरी ह्रीं ह्रीं क्रीं क्रीं क्रीं ॐ ||
>
> English : Om Kreem Kreem Kreem Hreem Hreem Swapneshwaree Hreem Hreem
>   Kreem Kreem Kreem Om ||

**Dreaming about lord Shiva** : [Appearance](http://www.astrobhriguvision.com/dreams.php) of Lord Shiva in the dream is extremely benevolent. This also signifies end of the crisis period.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing Lord Shiva drinking off human skull being as tall and white as the Kailasa cliff can indicate destruction.

In [Mahabharata Sabha-Parva Chapter 46](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02045.htm)

we find Maharshi Vyasa telling what is going to come in the future to Yudhisthira. Vyasa thus told Yudhisthira that he officially will  be the sole  cause of the destruction of all Kshatriyas  in Kurukshetra war  for the sins of Duryodhana.

> Vaisampayana continued,--"Hearing these words of the king, the exalted
> son of Parasara, the island-born Vyasa of dark hue, spoke these
> words,--'For thirteen years, O king, those portents will bear mighty
> consequences ending in destruction, O king of kings, of all the
> Kshatriyas. In course of time, O bull of the Bharata race, making thee
> the sole cause, the assembled Kshatriyas of the world will be
> destroyed, O Bharata, for the sins of Duryodhana
> and through the might of Bhima and Arjuna.

Vyasa then told Yudhishthira about a dream where he will see Shiva.

> In thy dream, O king
> of kings thou wilt behold towards the end of this might the blue
> throated Bhava, the slayer of Tripura, ever absorbed in meditation,
> having the bull for his mark, drinking off the human skull, and fierce
> and terrible, that lord of all creatures, that god of gods, the
> husband of Uma, otherwise called Hara and Sarva, and Vrisha, armed
> with the trident and the bow called Pinaka, and attired in tiger skin.
> And thou wilt behold Siva, tall and white as the Kailasa cliff and
> seated on his bull, gazing unceasingly towards the direction (south)
> presided over by the king of the Pitris. Even this will be the dream
> thou wilt dream today.