# Significance of dreaming of shivji

Tags: shiva

I had a dream of lord shiva standing he was completely white. He was standing right in the center of  a wooden bark artifact that I have above my bed. 
Saw it twice. Will never forget the image

Comment: Pure dream questions are off topic for site. Ask this to a proper Guru, he alone can guide you here on what you saw was Maya of mind or true vision of Shiva!

Comment: It is not advisable to express such divine dreams to all. If you feel love and devotion to Shiva, surrender tomHim.He will show you the path, thus spake our saints.

Comment: Pl never disclose to anyone any further.

Comment: Dreams are not interesting. Christians dream about Jesus, flatearthers dream about a flat earth. Whatever is on your mind you dream about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Dream' of Lord Shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21921/dream-of-lord-shiva)

Comment: Shruti,man you’re lucky!